# How to set the opacity of a shape and its text?

Tags: opacity, animated-gif, mermaid

### Context

Mermaidjs does not natively support animation. I need to create gif files similar to [this](https://blog.lmorchard.com/2023/01/03/mermaid-animations/):

[image: animated graph]

The problem with this approach is that the graph is always re-arranged whenever a new node is added to the graph. It makes harder to follow the flow.

### My Attempt

My idea was to add all nodes and edges to each "frame" and change their opacity.

In mermaid we could not use `rbga` to specify opacity so, I did the following trick.

#### First frame

```
graph TD
    start[Start]
    middle[Process]
    stop[Stop]

    start -- calls --> middle
    middle -- notifies --> stop

    %% Step 1 - hide everything except the start
    %% Step 2 - comment out related assets
    %% Step 3 - comment out related assets

    %% Frame 2's assets
    linkStyle 0 opacity:.1,color:#0001
    style middle opacity:.1,color:#0001

    %% Frame 3's assets
    linkStyle 1 opacity:.1,color:#0001
    style stop opacity:.1,color:#0001
```

#### Middle frame

```
graph TD
    start[Start]
    middle[Process]
    stop[Stop]

    start -- calls --> middle
    middle -- notifies --> stop

    %% Step 1 - hide everything except the start
    %% Step 2 - comment out related assets
    %% Step 3 - comment out related assets

    %% Frame 2's assets
    %% linkStyle 0 opacity:.1,color:#0001
    %% style middle opacity:.1,color:#0001

    %% Frame 3's assets
    linkStyle 1 opacity:.1,color:#0001
    style stop opacity:.1,color:#0001
```

#### Last frame

```
graph TD
    start[Start]
    middle[Process]
    stop[Stop]

    start -- calls --> middle
    middle -- notifies --> stop

    %% Step 1 - hide everything except the start
    %% Step 2 - comment out related assets
    %% Step 3 - comment out related assets

    %% Frame 2's assets
    %% linkStyle 0 opacity:.1,color:#0001
    %% style middle opacity:.1,color:#0001

    %% Frame 3's assets
    %% linkStyle 1 opacity:.1,color:#0001
    %% style stop opacity:.1,color:#0001
```

- The `opacity` controls the shape's opacity level
- The `color`'s last part controls the text's opacity level

For testing purposes I've used [ezgif's maker](https://ezgif.com/maker) to animate the `mmdc` generated frames:

[image: without re-arranging the graph]

### Problem

It did solve the re-arranging problem but it seems a bit clumsy. The background of the edge's annotation is still visible. In the previous sample I've used 10% opacity. But even if I use 0% is still visible.

[image: live editor]

[Related live editor link](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNqFksFOwzAMhl8lMkJcuint2pXlwAlxQ0IaJyiHqPG2iKapEhdRpr07LmOIIablYMXO99uy4y3U3iAoWAfdbcTjbdUKPpF0oOflaF_2EWeNafD5IfgaY3w5YL5jynfs_xKKyUTUumkiX26-lb-zjO-tJ7uyuEfGPIcMl5diSdiJVEzExhoU-IZhoI1t1wLfa-xI0Ab3hY4VGStq7xy2JHxPImCjCY3QMSLFY3Z2hv2h74J2KLKreJSmse3rkgZuRQrf6drSoGRS-8YHdSH5HKYxIt9Nn-D-VJqdrJSerzTO8X8KEnAYnLaG_3o7airgMTqsQPHV4Er3DVVQtTtGdU9-ObQ1KAo9JtB3hqdzazVviQO10k3kKBpLPtzv9-drjRLodPvkvTsI2QW1hXdQeTGVMivy6ywty3KW5wkMoObThUyzspTzgm26S-DjSy2ni5TjzOdFUeZyNt99AnhB1fk)

Is there anyway to hide the background of the edge's annotation?

Comment: I've just [filed an issue](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/5174) on github related to this.

Comment: Yeah, might be related to [this line of code/comment](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/blob/60280361b0c89a96f6d377e34f7f5cd32b52c775/packages/mermaid/src/diagrams/flowchart/flowRenderer.js#L58) because it seems like you cannot set various properties on a `linkStyle`.

Comment: @Jeroen As far as I can see if I set both (`opacity` and `color`) then they have an impact on the edge rendering. If I set only the `opacity` then the arrow is not visible but the annotation with its grey rectangle background is visible. If I set only the `color` then the annotation's text is not visible but the arrow and the annotation's grey rectangle background are visible.

Comment: That's quaint! Thanks for sharing. Curious to see what responses come in on GitHub.

Comment: @Jeroen With over 800 open issues I don't expect a solution soon :(